# Unit tests for various versions of windows

Tags: c#, unit-testing, cross-platform

I have a C# program that works on my environment but won't run on my coworkers system. I have windows 10 and they have windows 7.

How can I setup my unit test to run as if they were in windows 7?

The only way I've heard how to do this would be to implement docker. There has to be a simpler way of testing different versions of windows in Visual Studio.

If unit tests is not the place to change the testing OS where would I go to run under a different OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing a sample of the unit tests in question I couldn't begin to give you a more precise answer though, but here are some stabs:

A unit test shouldn't fail because it's running on a different version of Windows, rather I suspect the Windows 7 machine doesn't have the same version of dotnet installed.

That or the Window 7 machine might be 32-bit and yours is 64-bit, that too might be causing the problem.

Comment: Also what exception are you seeing, or what happens when you try to run the test, some more details would greatly help.

Comment: No exceptions are happening on unit tests. My unit tests work within the bounds of my program but when I tried my deployed/published program on my coworkers environment the program would load do a few things and then silently crash out. I just wanted to set up my unit tests so an exception would be thrown on methods that would fail on my coworkers environment.  So I should check my coworkers dotnet installed version?

Comment: That is possible, but I would have expected a warning when you installed it on your co-workers machine.  What did you build the installer with?  It never hurts to make sure he has all of the latest versions of the dotnet framework installed.

Do you have any logging in your application?  Consider outputting some simple logging to see what exactly is going on in your application.  Failing that use a try/catch block around your primary entry point and pop up a modal with any errors it catches as a down and dirty way of seeing what's going on.

Comment: One click deployment. Note: No one has admin access so I can't install something that requires admin credentials to install.

Comment: I added this to the edit, so not sure if you saw it, 
"Do you have any logging in your application? Consider outputting some simple logging to see what exactly is going on in your application. Failing that use a try/catch block around your primary entry point and pop up a modal with any errors it catches as a down and dirty way of seeing what's going on."

Comment: Since my coworker isn't a programmer and they need their computer to do their work I don't have access to it all the time. (Like today where they are working from home on an important "Do not disturb me" task.) The logging I had told me that the program hung up on a lock variable that I use to get my threads to wait to access the MS Access DB. I assume the previous thread crashed and never released the lock. That's as far as I got before my coworker left on Friday. Now its Monday and I'm trying to find out how to debug it without having to have their actual computer in front of me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200519/discussion-between-alec-ruderman-and-mandelbrotter).